# Delete all rows which contains 2 or more @ characters

Tags: notepad++, notepad

Is there a way in notepad ++ to delete all rows which contain 2 or more @ characters on the same row? I have a big list of email addresses. Some email addresses are incorrect because there are multiple @ characters in it. I want to delete these lines from the file.

If not possible, is this maybe possible in another app?

Thanks you

Comment: Email addresses may have multiple `@` inside quotation marks like `"blah@blah@blah"@example.org`, Have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the find & replace feature of notepad++

   Find `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)`
   Replace: `\r\n$&\r\n`
2. Use the mark feature

   Mark: `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)`
   have `Bookmark Line` checked.
3. Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines

This will basically create a line before and after every valid email address, then bookmark all email addresses (their lines) and then remove the rest

Comment: [Valid & invalid email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^.*@.*@.*$
Replace: (empty)
```